# Compiler Error when creating and editing OLEObject in same function

Tags: excel, vba, activex

When running the function it seems like it doesn't create the DropDown menu before it tries to add items, and therefore it runs into the compile-time error:

> Method or data member not found

Highlighting the `SomeNameToo` identifier.

[image: screenshot of compile error]

If I put the two "AddItem" lines into another function *and run that afterwards*, then there's no problem, and the two lines are added.

Is there a way of making it create the object before running the following code? This saves me having a lot of functions.

```
Sub hey()

ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Link:=False, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=100, Height:=20).Name = "SomeNameToo"

Sheet1.SomeNameToo.AddItem "Item 1"
Sheet1.SomeNameToo.AddItem "Item 2"

End Sub
```

Comment: What error message are you getting? Please post it as text in the question, not as an image. Images are not always clear enough to read and the content can't be copied/pasted (to search, for example). Also, if this is erroring at run-time it's not a compiler error - if that's the case the title should be corrected. You can use the [edit] link below the question to change its content.

Comment: I see two things you might try: 1) Put `Do Events` in a line between creating the control and adding items; 2) Assign the control to an object and use that (instead of `.Sheet1.SomeNameToo.AddItem`). Short version: `Dim oDD as Object : Set oDD = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(etc.) : oDD.AddItem "Item 1" `

Comment: Thanks Cindy Meister, but Mathieu's comment explained the reason to my problem.
I've tried to put the Do Events in between but that didn't work. I think it's just the way the program executes the code, and that I need to change my setup/workflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object doesn't exist at compile-time; `SomeNameToo` doesn't exist when the code is being compiled, only after the `OLEObjects.Add` method has executed.

The `Add` method *returns* a reference to the object being created.

You are accessing that object, once - here:

```
.Name = "SomeNameToo"
```

...and then the object is up in the air, with nothing to hold on to it in that procedure's scope.

Declare an `OLEObject` variable to hold that reference:

```
Dim oleControl As OLEObject
Set oleControl = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(...)
```

Then use that object:

```
oleControl.Name = "SomeNameToo"
```

Or, capture the returned reference using a `With` block - then you don't need a local variable:

```
With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(...)
    .Name = "SomeNameToo"
End With
```

Now, you can't invoke `AddItem` against that object, because an `OLEObject` isn't a `ComboBox` and doesn't know anything about an `AddItem` method. You want to work with the wrapped MSForms `ComboBox` control - that's `OLEObject.Object`:

```
With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(...)
    .Name = "SomeNameToo"
    With .Object
        .AddItem "Item 1"
        .AddItem "Item 2"
    End With
End With
```

Or, with local variables:

```
Dim oleControl As OLEObject
Set oleControl = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(...)
oleControl.Name = "SomeNameToo"

Dim msFormsControl As MSForms.ComboBox
Set msFormsControl = oleControl.Name
msFormsControl.AddItem "Item 1"
msFormsControl.AddItem "Item 2"
```

Note that without local variables, you're coding against `Object`, which means everything is late-bound and can't be validated at compile-time: a typo will result in error 438.

With local variables and declared types, everything is compiler-validated and you get *IntelliSense* to assist as you type.

Comment: Thank you. Yes my problem was that the object didn't exist, and this explains why.